# Wikipedia API: How to get all pageIDs for all persons with same name?

Tags: wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I see some of the persons with same name.

such as Rico Rodriguez

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rico_Rodriguez

shows there are 2 person (pageIDs)

but by using this api, i can only get one pageID

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Rico_Rodriguez&format=json
```

How can I get all of the two persons' pageIDs?

Answer (score 4):

As leo mentioned, on Wikipedia, you would have to analyze the Disambiguation page. However, wikidata.org is now collecting data sets about things described on wikipedia. Wikidata has the notion of "labels" and "aliases", which can be the same for multiple pages, and are defiend per language. Here is a query that you can use to find all Wikidata entries for "Rico Rodriguez":

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=Rico%20Rodriguez&language=en

You can then ask for the "sitelinks" of each of those "data items":

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q552090|Q954614&props=aliases|sitelinks&languages=en

That will give you the corresponding page titles on each Wikipedia language version. You can then go to the respective wiki's API and ask for the page ID.

Answer (score 0):

All MediaWiki page titles are unique, and disambiguition is handled manually by the editors, so there is no way to know for sure if there are multiple persons with the same name. You can, however, check if the page is a disambiguation page, as in your example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Rico_Rodriguez&prop=pageprops
```

returns `disambiguation` under `pageprops`.

To get the pages linked, you will have to parse the wiki code, though. Disambiguation links can look any way, really, so there will be no easy way to catch them all, but as long as you work within one single language edition, there is a fair chance that the syntax will be more or less consistent. In English Wikipedia, that would [usually be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDisambiguation) either `Rico Rodriguez (musician)`, or [`Kimberley, British Columbia`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimberley).

An disambiguation page can be very complex, though. For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joker

Comment: You could also list all the links on the disambiguation page using the API.